# How can do center a UWP app on the screen?

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I want my universal app to be in the center of the screen. I know that it is easy with windows form, but have no idea how can do it in the universal windows app.

Thanks

Comment: Probably it's not possible, you can only choose if the app is fullscreen or not, if it's not fullscreen its position is managed by the system.

Comment: @w.b , is it possible to get the x and y of the app on the screen ?

Comment: Again, I don't think so, you can get the window bounds, or if the app is on the left/right side of the screen (`ApplicationView.AdjacentToLeftDisplayEdge` / `AdjacentToRightDisplayEdge`), but check classes like `ApplicationView`, `Window`, `CoreWindow` etc.

Comment: @pixel come on dude :) this question is about two years old